# What can cause mysql_query to seg fault?

Tags: c++, mysql

```
mysql_ping(mysql);
mysql_query(mysql, query.c_str());
```

When I run the above code in one client it runs fine. When I run more than one client simultaneously it will seg fault about half the time. I know that "mysql" is not NULL and "query" is a properly formatted SELECT query. I couldn't find anything about mysql_query ever seg faulting.

Comment: Can you get a reproducible example for the input?

Comment: Can you elaborate what your "client" *is*? A separate *thread*? A separate *process*?

Comment: I have a server and I have two client processes running. Each client makes a query.

Comment: Are these client's `fork()` ed or are they independent processes, each independently opening their own mysql handle? Just curious. Normally the only time a query faults is when either the handle is indeterminate (wasn't initialized properly) or the query string is said-same.

Comment: They are independent processes. In one terminal I run "./server" and in another terminal window I run "./client & ./client"

Comment: I was just informed that another part of the project was significantly reworked making the part I was working on thread unsafe. Sorry to waste everyone's time, but it looks like I'll just to have to throw in a mutex.